# How can i Remove \n (Char(10)) from specific string from starting & Ending of the string in ms sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one column for comment and I need to show this for one report. 
Here what happen some time, users uses multiple enters in comment box. I can not access code part I need to manage this thing in SQL only.

So I have removed unwanted

```
1 /r/n 
2 /n/n
```

from using

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(Desc, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), CHAR(10)),CHAR(10)+CHAR(10), CHAR(10)) as Desc,
```

Now I want to remove any `\r` or `\n` from **starting or ending** of the string if any

Answer (score 4):

Use TRIM check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

Example : `UPDATE tablename SET descriptions = TRIM(TRAILING "<br>" FROM descriptions)`
if you want to replace newline then use something like below

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@str, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

or

```
DECLARE @testString varchar(255)
set @testString = 'MY STRING      '

 /*Select the string and try to copy and paste into notepad and tab is still there*/
SELECT testString = @testString 

/*Ok, it seems easy, let's try to trim this. Huh, it doesn't work, the same result here.*/
SELECT testStringTrim = RTRIM(@testString) 

/*Let's try to get the size*/
SELECT LenOfTestString = LEN(@testString) 

/*This supposed to give us string together with blank space, but not for tab though*/
SELECT DataLengthOfString= DATALENGTH(@testString)

SELECT ASCIIOfTab = ASCII(' ')
SELECT CHAR(9) 

/*I always use this like a final solution*/
SET @testString = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@testString, CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '') SELECT @testString   

/*
CHAR(9)       - Tab
CHAR(10) - New Line
CHAR(13) - Carriage Return
*/
```

[Reference](http://sqlsrv4living.blogspot.in/2012/11/remove-tab-new-line-and-return-carriage.html)

Comment: I want for MS SQL. And this will remove the white space not new line like /n /r (char(10) or char (13))

Answer (score 4):

By the way you meant in your question:(Remove char(10) or char(13) from specific string)
Note: You should see the output result by switching your resultset output to **Results to Text(Ctrl+T)**.

**Results to Text**

[image: Results to Ttext:]

**Results to Grid**

[image: Results to Grid:]

Comment: Yes this is useful but What exactly i wanted is to omit char(10) or char(13) from specific string from starting of string or ending of string only. We can not remove all  char(10) or char(13) .

For Example "  ABCXYZ  "
Consider here before ABC we have  char(10) or char(13) then only we need to replace it. same WAY if it's at end of the string after XYZ
then only we need to perform replace for char(10) or char(13) .

Answer (score 0):

```
select dbo.trim('abc','c') -- ab
select dbo.trim('abc','a') -- bc
select dbo.trim(' b ',' ') -- b
```

[image]

Create a user-define-function: trim()

trim from both sides

trim any letter: space, \r, \n, etc

```
Create FUNCTION Trim
(
    @Original varchar(max), @letter char(1)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @rtrim varchar(max)
    SELECT @rtrim = iif(right(@original, 1) = @letter, left(@original,datalength(@original)-1), @original)
    return iif( left(@rtrim,1) =  @letter, right(@rtrim,datalength(@rtrim)-1),@rtrim)
END
```